# Unwanted spaces added in print function call

Tags: python

```
Number of characters in yellow_Daisy : 12
Number of characters in 6yellow6 : 8
```

how can I move the : closer to the words.
here is what I wrote but I don't know how to get read of the space

```
print('Number of characters in', password1,':', len(password1))
print('Number of characters in', password2,':', len(password2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, please make sure your title concisely summarizes your question so we can decide whether to click on it. This title tells us nothing useful (and invites downvotes because ["can somebody help me?" is not a real question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)).

Comment: strip() function will remove leading and trailing whitespaces, if thats what you are trying to ask for

Comment: This won't exactly solve your question, but for sake of completeness: You can specify a `sep` parameter to the function which will be used to combine the comma-separated strings. Example: `print("a", "b", "c", sep="-")` prints `a-b-c`. The default for `sep` is a whitespace, which is what you're observing.

Answer (score 3):

f-strings to the rescue.

```
print(f'Number of characters in {password1}: {len(password1)}')
print(f'Number of characters in {password2}: {len(password2)}')
```

With f-strings (python 3.6 and later), you can put python expressions in curly braces. Now you have a single string with the spacing and formatting you want, and `{..}` will be replaced with the evaluation of the expression.

Comment: You might want to mention that f-strings are 3.6+.

Comment: @MattDMo - Good point. I figured 3.6 was long ago, but it was really only 2016. Python's before 3.6 which don't have f-strings are also no longer getting updates and should be considered dead for most of us. Still, good to note.

Comment: We still get Py2 questions from time to time, so better safe than sorry...

Answer (score 0):

try formatting the string as such:

`print("Number of characters in {a}:{b}".format(a=password1, b=len(password1)))`

or
`print(f"Number of characters in {password1}:{len(password1)}")`

Answer (score 0):

I think *tdelaney* has provided a great answer. Another simpler way (but not so clear as f-strings) is to use concatenation (+) instead of commas, e.g.

```
print('Number of characters in' + password1 + ':' + str(len(password1)))
```